# Asp.Net MVC: GridView Paging Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gridview

I have a problem with the gridview control. I've created a form with a dropdownlist, a retrieve button and a gridview control. I choose a value from the dropdownlist, i click the button and the gridview is filled with the data in 2 pages. When i click on the second page the data are gone. I must press again the retrieve button and then the second page is shown correctly. I have used the PageIndexChanging but its nothing changed.Any ideas?

Comment: are you sure you are using MVC and not web forms? Are you using razor view engine? Can you show your View code?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure his data source hasn't been reset on postback.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        this.GridView1.DataSource = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\windows").GetFiles();
        this.GridView1.PageSize = 3;
        this.GridView1.AllowPaging = true;
        this.GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Implement PageIndexChanging method to the grid... like example.

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    this.GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
}
```

Comment: Paulo MVC has no post back nor Page_Load concept ! ;-)

Comment: he is talking about webforms issue.. probably the title is wrong... i think... I should not have answered